# Can we change the name of testng.xml to some other name? Instead of testng.xml can I make it like myproject.xml?

Tags: selenium, testng

In my test automation project we are dynamically creating xml file for running tests. but im not able to find testng.xml file instead I got something like myproject.xml which looks like a testng.xml. Is it possible to create a testng.xml in different name? or am I referring to a wrong file?

Answer (score 1):

you can change the name of Testng.xml or you  can use any name for xml File where we can execute test cases. But Keep in mind. if you rename testng.xml you have to change name accordingly on Pom.xml also.
In other we can understand well by another example that while we uses group of test case module wise in Test suite we use different name of each xml file . So there is no mendatory rule to use name Testng.xml

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `testng.xml` file can be renamed as anything, as long as the `.xml` extension is present and you keep consistency with the new name all through the project. For example, when I do cross-browser testing using TestNG, I rename the file as `crossbrowser.xml`. That way, anyone reading through the code will know right away the purpose of the file, as the name suggests. I find the name `testng.xml` is too generic for my liking.